# SOAP - Need to understand the error I get

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

I'm trying to initialize a variable called proxy like this:

`proxy = Savon::Client.new "http://192.168.1.1:8080"`

The thing is, when I run my code, I  only get the error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant NameOfTheClass::Savon`

Thanks for any help!

PD: I'm using Ruby 1.9.2

PD2: I'm trying to run this from console.

Comment: Don't know you using ruby1.9 or not but I heard ruby 1.9 drop soap library from builtins, is that be issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found probably the documentation for versions < 0.8.x.
Unfortunately the syntax has changed! Have a look here: https://github.com/rubiii/savon/blob/master/README.md

Savon works with blocks now.
Your example should now look like this

```
require 'savon'
require 'pp'

proxy = Savon::Client.new do 
  wsdl.document = "http://my.webservices.net/service?wsdl"
end

pp proxy.wsdl.soap_actions
```

Comment: Thanks! You were right... i'm now using a more up to date manual and doin' fine!